# How can I get my for loop to execute into localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically create an array (items=[]) and store the information so all the objects in the array are listed inside of the `localstorage`. But my jQuery `for` loop is not working? Everything works but my lines from the for loop jQuery to the `localstorage`. I am not sure if I made some sort of typo or using the wrong variables inside the loop.

```js
var shoppingFormEl = $('#shopping-form');
var shoppingListEl = $('#shopping-list');
   
// TODO: Create a function to handle the form submission event that captures the form's <input>` value and prints it to the `shoppingListEl` as a `<li>`
    
function handleFormSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var shoppingInput = $('input[name="shopping-input"]').val();
    
  if (!shoppingInput) {
    alert(`please enter a value in the input field`);
    return;
  }

  var items = []
  shoppingListEl.append(`<li> ${shoppingInput} </li>`);
  $('input[name="shopping-input"]').val(''); // removes it from input textbox
  // console.log(shoppingInput);
    
  $.each(shoppingInput, function() {
    items.push($(this).val());
  });
    
  localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items)); /// try again with making the array             so all items appear in localstorage not one at a time
  //added to practice local storage
    
}

// TODO: Add an event listener to the `shoppingFormEl` to handle submission

shoppingFormEl.on("submit", handleFormSubmit);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>jQuery Shopping List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/jass.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body class="bg-dark text-light">
  <main class="my-5 mx-auto">
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <hr />

    <h2>Add an item to the list.</h2>
    <form id="shopping-form">
      <input type="text" class="form-input w-100" id="shopping-input" name="shopping-input"
        placeholder="Enter item name" />
      <button class="btn btn-info">Add Item</button>
   </form>

   <ul id="shopping-list"></ul>
  </main>

  <!-- Added link to the jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Your JavaScript file -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/script.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How do you know the content is not being saved to local storage?

Comment: What for loop? Do you mean `$.each(shoppingInput, ...)`?

Comment: `shoppingInput` is a string, not an array, so there's nothing to loop over.

Comment: Also `$.each(shoppingInput` does not make sense. The variable "shoppingInput" contains the value string from the input element. jQuery will not do anything with that. In fact it's not clear why you'd need a loop at all; there's only one value. Your code should load the existing list from local storage, add the new item, and then save it back. No loop necessary.

Comment: There should be a console error from `$.each(shoppingInput, ...)`

Comment: for each- shopping input I am putting each value into the array "items". And yes there is an error but I don't quite understand it.

 jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in food
    at p (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:1077)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:2937)
    at HTMLFormElement.handleFormSubmit (script.js:20:7)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:43090)
    at v.handle (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:41074)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is iterating over the string entered into the text input, not `localStorage`, which doesn't make much sense since the user will be entering one item at a time, so there is no array, collection, or array-like object to loop over (except the characters in the string, but that's not what you want either).

I'm not even sure why you feel you need an array or a loop here. All you need to do is store HTML string contents of the `ul` into `localStorage` and then return that string back to the DOM upon page load.

The code below won't work here in Stack Overflow due to sandboxing, but it will work out at [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1kbm5xc/).

```js
// Static element references should be gottten just once
// rather than every time the function runs. Also, best
// practice is to set your references to the element(s)
// and not properties of the element(s) so that if you
// need to get a second property value, you won't have
// to re-scan the DOM for the same element again.
const shoppingFormEl = $('#shopping-form');
const shoppingListEl = $('#shopping-list');
const shoppingInput = $('input[name="shopping-input"]');

$(function(){
  // this code runs when the DOM is ready so this is the place to
  // restore the list from localStorage
  shoppingListEl.html(localStorage.getItem("items"));
});
   
shoppingFormEl.on("submit", handleFormSubmit);
    
function handleFormSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
    
  if (!shoppingInput.val()) {
    alert(`please enter a value in the input field`);
    shoppingInput.focus();  // Put focus back into input    
    return;
  }

  // Don't pad the list item with spaces
  shoppingListEl.append(`<li>${shoppingInput.val()}</li>`);
  $("#shopping-input").val(''); // removes it from input textbox
  
  // No need for a loop, array, or JSON.stringify(). Just put the contents of the ul into localStorage
  localStorage.setItem("items", shoppingListEl.html());  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>jQuery Shopping List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/jass.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body class="bg-dark text-light">
  <main class="my-5 mx-auto">
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <hr>

    <h2>Add an item to the list.</h2>
    <form id="shopping-form">
      <input type="text" class="form-input w-100" id="shopping-input" name="shopping-input"
        placeholder="Enter item name" />
      <button class="btn btn-info">Add Item</button>
   </form>

   <ul id="shopping-list"></ul>
  </main>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/script.js">
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```